# Remove nested loops in R with map or apply

Tags: r, loops, apply, nested-loops

I have a list of vectors in R:

```
test_list <- list()

test_list[[1]] <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
test_list[[2]] <- c(1,2,3)
test_list[[3]] <- c(6,7)
test_list[[4]] <- c(9,10,11)
```

And I want to check the intersection of each vector with all the other vectors. A nested loop approach would look like this:

```
for(i in test_list) {
 for(j in test_list) {
      intersect(i, j)
}

}
```

And the results would look like this:

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 6 7
numeric(0)
[1] 1 2 3
[1] 1 2 3
numeric(0)
numeric(0)
[1] 6 7
numeric(0)
[1] 6 7
numeric(0)
numeric(0)
numeric(0)
numeric(0)
[1]  9 10 11
```

I have seen that I can remove one of the foor loops using map or apply:

```
  get_overlap_cells <- function(x) {
    
    for(i in test_list) {
     
      overlaping_cells <- intersect(i, x) 
    } 
  }

r <- map(test_list, get_overlap_cells)
```

However, I would like to remove both loops, any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: I would like to compute the intersect of each pair of vectors, without loops. My list of vectors is huge, and each vector has a high dimension. Doing this with foor loops takes more than 3 hours.

Comment: The list you have, can you include the results you want from it

Comment: I just added them. The results would be the intersection of test_list[[1]] with test_list[[2]],  test_list[[1]] with test_list[[3]],  test_list[[1]] with test_list[[4]], then test_list[[2]] with test_list[[1]],  test_list[[2]] with test_list[[2]]... and so on

Comment: `c(outer(test_list, test_list, Vectorize(intersect)))` will get you the result you specify but it's wasteful - there's little point finding the intersect of a vector against itself nor finding the intersect of `xy` and `yx`.  `combn(seq_along(test_list), 2, FUN = \(i) intersect(test_list[[i[1]]], test_list[[i[2]]]), simplify = FALSE)` is likely a better approach.

Comment: That code is repetetive and will be tedious for no good reason. ie intersect of [1], [1] is the same as [1], intersect of [1], [2] is the same as intersect of [2], [1] so why repeat?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento `combn(test_list, 2, do.call, what = 'intersect', simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: @onyambu How could I get the indices of each combination?In other words, this approach will not compute the intersection of 1-1, and for example, it will compute the intersection of 1-2 but not 2-1. I would like to get a list with the number of intersections per each pair of the test_list. Such that: 1-1 : 0, 1-2: 3, 1-3: 2, ... 2-1: 0, 2-2: 0, 2-3: ..... thank you!

Comment: @JonathanF first note that intersection is commutative, ie AnB = BnA unless you have a different meaning of intersection. Second AnA= A. Hence you do not need to calculate the intersections of 2-1 since its the same as 1-2 and also no need to calculate intersection of 1-1 since its just 1. You just need the correct indices to call the specified intersections

Comment: @onyambu Yes, that's exactly what I want and that's what your method is doing. However, I would also like to get the indices of the commputed intersection. For example, if I have 4 vectors in my test_list, and I am computing the intersection of each pair, instead of returning 16 intersections it will return 6, because of the commutative property. I would like to output what pairs are computed. For example: 1-2, 1-3, .... So then I know which intersection corresponds to each pair

Answer (score 1):

```
combins <- expand.grid(seq_along(test_list), seq_along(test_list))
mapply( function(x,y) intersect(test_list[[x]],test_list[[y]]), 
        combins[,1], combins[,2])
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 6 7

[[4]]
numeric(0)

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[6]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[7]]
numeric(0)

[[8]]
numeric(0)

[[9]]
[1] 6 7

[[10]]
numeric(0)

[[11]]
[1] 6 7

[[12]]
numeric(0)

[[13]]
numeric(0)

[[14]]
numeric(0)

[[15]]
numeric(0)

[[16]]
[1]  9 10 11
```